# Send List between forms

Tags: c#, forms, list

How do you send a list between two forms?
Let's say I have form1 which looks somewhat like...

```
public partial class form1 : Form
{
    public form1()
    {
         List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
         Form2 form2 = new Form2(int test);
         form2.show();
    }
}
```

And the other form called form2 looks like...

```
public partial class form2 : Form
{
    public button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
        list2.add(5);
        list2.add(test);
    }
}
```

Now my question is - how can I send list2 from form2 to form1 and make list1 = list2.
Hope I explained somewhat understandable.

Comment: Create a `Form2` constructor that accepts a list

Comment: And how do you do that? Im not too good at programming.

Comment: `public Form2(List<int> myList)`

Comment: But it's not from public Form2, it's supposed to be sent from public button1_click

Comment: @user3501058: Just to be clear, Do you need to pass a `List` from `Form1` to `Form2` ??

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, create a constructor in `Form1` that takes a `List<T>`:

```
public partial class form1 : Form
{
    private List<int> _list;
    public Form1(List<int> list)
    {  
        this._list = list;
    }
}
```

Button click:

```
public button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> list2 = new List<int>();
    list2.add(5);
    list2.add(test); //assuming this is a typo?

    Form1 myform = new Form1(list2);
}
```

You could also create a property on `Form1` and assign the list to it after instantiation:

```
Form1 myform = new Form1();
myform.MyList = list;
```

Comment: why form2 needs `List<int>` in constructor as OP pass single integer to Form2?

Comment: The OP is passing a list between forms (read the title/question). Not a single integer. `how can I send list2 from form2 to form1 and make list1 = list2`

Comment: What I can see is OP passing a single value to Form2 and add some values along with the one passed from Form1 to a `List` sitting on Form2 and return that List to Form1 ?

Comment: Read the question: `Now my question is - how can I send list2 from form2 to form1 and make list1 = list2`. There is no mention of passing a single int between forms. Since he wants `Form1` to have a copy of the list in `Form2` you would simply add the integer to the list before passing it into the constructor rather than passing an int...

Comment: I though other way because, in `Form1` OP try to pass `int test` to `Form2` and the `Form2` button_click event try to add that value `test` and some other value to the `List` in `Form2`

Comment: His example is clearly wrong though `Form2 form2 = new Form2(int test);` is not valid code. I suspect this is a typo as it is at odds with the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create **form2** constructor which accept the `list as a parameter`.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   private List<int> listofInt;
   public Form2(List<int> list)
   {  
     listofInt = list;
   }
}
```

**Form1** click event

```
public button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 List<int> list = new List<int>();
 list.Add(1);
 list.Add(2);
 list.Add(3);
 Form2 myform = new Form2(list2);
}
```

Here Form2 `constructor` accept list.

Comment: You've got it wrong. Form2 should send the list via a button_click, and Form1 should recieve it without an event.